# Requests, BeautifulSoup <Tabelas>

Tags: html, python-3.x, python-requests, beautifulsoup

Eu tenho um site que quero extrair dados especifico  de uma tabela
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quero extrair todas as informações que tiver elemento "PROLONG".

A minha dificuldade e que todas as tabelas tem o mesmo nome na "class" class="field".
como eu faço para extrair os dados relacionados ao elemento "PROLONG"
codigo que eu fiz:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('http://www.praticagem-rj.com.br/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "lxml")

list_return = soup.find_all('td', class_='field')

for list_dados in list_return:
    print(list_dados.next_element)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código deste site é uma bagunça. O que está acontecendo no seu código, é que você está buscando coluna por coluna em todas as linhas da tabela. Pode notar que se você ler diferentes itens da lista *list_return* eles podem ou não pertencer à mesma linha da tabela.

O que você precisa então, é pegar apenas as linhas interessantes, e dentro delas procurar as que contêm "PROLONG"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('http://www.praticagem-rj.com.br/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "lxml")
list_return = soup.find_all('tr',style="background: #e4e4e4;")
for tr in list_return:
temp = tr.find('td', class_='field', text='PROLONG')
if temp != None:
    print(tr)
    print("-----")
```

Do objeto 'soup', separei todas as linhas que pertencem à tabela em 'list_return'. Em seguida, itero sobre cada linha procurando se ela possui uma coluna com o texto='PROLONG'. As linhas que não tem essa coluna retornam None na busca, as que tem são chamadas no print.
[image: Algoritmo em ação]

**PS: A chave para procurar as coisas com BeautifulSoup é já saber o que procurar usando a função de 'inspecionar objeto' no navegador. Foi assim que descobri como isolar as linhas da tabela usando** style="background: #e4e4e4;"